# How to add a MultiPageEditor into a MultiPageEditor as a sub editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When I tried to use addPage() to put a customized multipage editor into the Multipage editor, I found that the customized multipage editor won't display. Is there anyone who encountered the same problem and if there is any solution?

the codes are as follow

```
    private void createMultiPage() {
    try {
        multiPageEditor = new CustomizedMultiPageEditor();
        int index = addPage(multiPageEditor, getEditorInput());
        setPageText(index, "Customized MultiPage");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("opps!!!");
    }

}
```